# UButtonl.titleLabel iOS 8 bug

Tags: cocoa-touch, uibutton, uikit, uilabel, ios8

So I have these interesting results on iOS 8 that prevent my app from working correctly.

I use `UIButton.titleLabel` to correctly set `titleEdgeInsets`. It works flawlessly on iOS7:

```
    [self.btnAccSets setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -(self.btnAccSets.width - (self.btnAccSets.titleLabel.width + 34)), 0, 0)];
```

But in iOS 8 it just doesn't work. If I debug the `UIButton.titleLabel`, I see this in console (pay attention to the frame parameter):

```
<UIButtonLabel: 0x7fcdd2c40f90; frame = (21 15; 98 18); text = 'Game settings'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fcdd2c44410>>
```

And in iOS 8 I get this (compare the frames):

```
<UIButtonLabel: 0x7f928943b1d0; frame = (148 24; 0 0); text = 'Game settings'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f9289435760>>
```

What are my next steps to debug this? What can be wrong? Is it really an iOS 8 bug?